# How can I draw Circular sector with three empty fraction?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, asymptote, smartdiagram

How can I draw Circular sector with three empty fraction and box between of them as following image?

[image]

The following code is not run and not equivalent. Also,  can I use **TikZ** one time instead of three times as the follows.

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
%=========================
%                 \draw  circle 
%==========================
\newcount\segmentsleft
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  circle fraction/.style args={#1/#2}{code={%
\segmentsleft=#1\relax
\pgfmathloop
\ifnum\segmentsleft<1\else
\ifnum\segmentsleft<#2 \edef\n{\the\segmentsleft}\else\def\n{#2}\fi
\begin{scope}[shift={(\pgfmathcounter,0)}]
\foreach \i [evaluate={\a=360/#2*(\i-1)+90;}] in {1,...,\n}
  \fill[fill=gray] (0,0) -- (\a:3/8) arc (\a:\a+360/#2:3/8) -- cycle;
\draw circle [radius=3/8];
\ifnum#2>1
  \foreach \i [evaluate={\a=360/#2*(\i-1);}] in {1,...,#2}
    \draw (0,0) -- (90+\a:3/8);
\fi
\end{scope}
\advance\segmentsleft by-#2
\repeatpgfmathloop
  }}
}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%                          
%                                        empty box
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\emptybox}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  %\noindent\framebox[#1]{\rule{0pt}{#2}}%
\noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
  \noindent \colorbox{lightgray} {\framebox[#1]{\rule{0pt}{#2}}}
}}
  \endgroup
}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                          empty frac
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\emptyfrac}[1][]{\tikz[baseline=-.6ex,#1]{
\noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
\draw (0,0)--
    node[above=1pt, fill=lightgray, minimum size=5mm]{}                     
    node[below=1pt, fill=lightgray, minimum size=5mm]{}(.5,0);}}   
}}      
%  \emptyfractwo
\newcommand{\emptyfractwo}[1][]{\tikz[baseline=-.6ex,#1]{
   \noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
 \draw (0,0)--
 %    node[above=-6pt, fill=lightgray, minimum size=5mm]{}                  
     node[above=-6pt, fill=lightgray, minimum size=5mm]{}(0,0);}}      
}}   
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  for empty circle
\newcommand{\emptycircle}{{
\noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
\tikz \draw[line width=0.6pt] circle(4mm);}}
}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \numerator/\denominator [count=\y]  in {3/2}{
\node at (0,-1) {$\emptyfractwo \;\emptyfrac$}; %  chnage using \emptyfrac
  \pic  at (-1.5, 0.3) {circle fraction={\numerator/\denominator}}; 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
%=========================
\hspace{1mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,-1) {$ \emptycircle$};
% \node at (0,-1) {$\frac{\emptybox[5mm]{5mm}}{}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1mm}
%=========================
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \numerator/\denominator [count=\y]  in { 11/10}{
 \node at (0,-1) {$ \emptyfractwo \;\emptyfrac$}; 
  \pic  at (-1.5, 0.3) {circle fraction={\numerator/\denominator}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the `circuitkz` tag? (And  most of the other, btw). You asked a very similar question about square fractions, what is that you missed there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the code from the [solution about rectangles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645012/125871) but use circular sectors:

[image]

The code for the above image is `\fraccirc{9}{12}\qquad\fraccirc[fill=blue!30]{3}{4}`. The default fill color is `orange!70`, but you can adjust this with an optional fill color. You can also add other tikz options, e.g. `scale=`, `rotate=`, etc.

Here is the code for the macro:

```
\newcommand{\fraccirc}[3][fill=orange!70]{\tikz[baseline, #1]{
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#2}{\fill[draw=black, thick] (0,0)--({90-360/#3*(\n-1)}:1) arc ({90-360/#3*(\n-1)}:{90-360/#3*\n}:1)--cycle;}
    \foreach \n in {#2,...,#3} {\draw[thick] (0,0)--({90-360/#3*(\n-1)}:1) arc ({90-360/#3*(\n-1)}:{90-360/#3*\n}:1)--cycle;}}}
```

You could also make additional macros `\wholecirc`, `\emptybox` and `\emptyframe` to make the rest of your images

[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\newcommand{\fracrect}[3][]{\tikz[baseline, #1]{
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#2}{\draw[thick, fill=orange!70] ({(\n-1)/#3},0) rectangle (\n/#3,1);}
    \foreach \n in {#2,...,#3} {\draw[thick] ({(\n-1)/#3},0) rectangle (\n/#3,1);}}}
\newcommand{\fraccirc}[3][fill=orange!70]{\tikz[baseline, #1]{
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#2}{\fill[draw=black, thick] (0,0)--({90-360/#3*(\n-1)}:.75) arc ({90-360/#3*(\n-1)}:{90-360/#3*\n}:.75)--cycle;}
    \foreach \n in {#2,...,#3} {\draw[thick] (0,0)--({90-360/#3*(\n-1)}:.75) arc ({90-360/#3*(\n-1)}:{90-360/#3*\n}:.75)--cycle;}}}
\newcommand{\wholecirc}[1][fill=orange!70]{\tikz[baseline, #1]{\fill[draw=black, thick] circle[radius=.75];}}
\newcommand{\emptyfrac}[1][]{\tikz[baseline=-.6ex,#1]{\draw (0,0)--
    node[above=1pt, fill=brown!20, minimum size=5mm]{}
    node[below=1pt, fill=brown!20, minimum size=5mm]{}(.5,0);}}
\newcommand{\emptybox}[1][]{\tikz[baseline=-.6ex, #1]{\node[fill=brown!20, minimum size=5mm]{}}}
\newcommand{\emptyframe}[1][]{\tikz[baseline=-.6ex, #1]{\node[draw=brown, thick, rounded corners, minimum size=5mm]{}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\wholecirc[fill=blue!30]\quad\wholecirc[fill=blue!30]\quad\fraccirc[fill=blue!30]{7}{8}\hspace{1cm}\wholecirc\quad\wholecirc\quad\fraccirc{5}{8}
\]

\[
\emptybox\,\emptyfrac\hspace{1cm}\emptyframe\hspace{1cm}\emptybox\,\emptyfrac
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sandy G, thanks again, please,  can you add code for empty boxes?

Comment: @workwolf: Done. You should experiment with the code and better familiarize yourself with the `\node` command. The pgf manual is a bit intimidating, but the tutorials at the beginning (especially chapters 2 and 3) will explain everything you need to get started.

Comment: +1 Dear, Sandy G , thanks so much, you're right.