# How to make `friends of 10' math tiles on overleaf

Tags: tables

I would really like to create these pictures to help with fractions. I know how to begin using tikz package. I am not sure how to go about setting it up so that I do not have to draw it separately each time. I would love to show something that I have started with but have no idea. And what if I wanted to make the rectangle horizontal and not vertical?

Thank you so much for any responses!

[image]

Comment: it seems like it's a simple table of filled or not filled circles, which wouldn't require tikz (or any package) but can you say something about how the table relates to the math expression at the end? What, in general, do you want to draw?

Comment: Hi. I want to do something similar to this. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645006/how-can-i-draw-rectangle-with-empty-fraction

Comment: so now I'm really confused as those blocks don't look anything like your sketch. I vaguely remember "friends of 10" meaning one of 0,10  1,9  2,8  3,7  4,6  5,5  6,4  7,3  8,2  9,1  10,0  so do you want a function that takes such a pair and draws a table, but how does the top two circles being filled relate to 2+8 ??

Comment: Yes to "a function that takes such a pair and draws a table". 
Visually seeing that 2(filled) and 8(not filled) makes 10, so does 3 (filled blue) and 7(not filled). My apologies that it is not so clear. Perhaps making them two different colours would make it easier.

Comment: that's what I expected, but I couldn't guess any way you have numbered the table cells such that the top row cells are 2 and 8 ?  Can you edit the question to give more information also say what "friends of 10" means (I only just remembered this) and which cells should be filled and which not filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ti*k*Z

Here's a quick solution via TikZ and a matrix node where you have to specify number of columns and rows yourself.

No, TikZ isn't really necessary and it can be improved …

Two global counters are used to keep track of the number of pills necessary.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{friendsPositive}
\newcounter{friendsNegative}
\tikzset{
  friends of positive/.style={draw, fill=blue!50},
  friends of negative/.style={draw, fill=none},
  friends of/.style args={#1+#2}{
    /utils/exec=\pgfmathsetcounter{friendsPositive}{#1}%
                \pgfmathsetcounter{friendsNegative}{#2},
    matrix, x=+5mm, y=+5mm, % xy scaling
    every outer matrix/.append style={% tight invisible matrix
      shape=rectangle, path only, inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt},
    row sep=+-\pgflinewidth, column sep=+-\pgflinewidth,
    execute at empty cell={
      \draw (-.5,-.5) rectangle (.5,.5);
      \ifnum\value{friendsPositive}>0
        \addtocounter{friendsPositive}{-1}
        \path[friends of positive] (0,0) circle[radius=.3];
      \else
        \ifnum\value{friendsNegative}>0
          \addtocounter{friendsNegative}{-1}
          \path[friends of negative] (0,0) circle[radius=.3];
        \fi
      \fi}}}
\begin{document}
Friends of $10 = \mathcolor{blue!50}{ 2} +  8$:
\tikz\matrix[friends of = 2 + 8]{ & \\ & \\ & \\ & \\ & \\};\par
Friends of $ 9 = \mathcolor{blue!50}{ 4} +  5$:
\tikz\matrix[friends of = 4 + 5]{ & & \\ & & \\ & & \\};\par
Friends of $16 = \mathcolor{blue!50}{ 7} +  9$:
\tikz\matrix[friends of = 7 + 9]{ & & & \\ & & & \\ & & & \\ & & & \\};\par
Friends of $24 = \mathcolor{blue!50}{12} + 12$:
\tikz\matrix[friends of = 12 + 12]{
  & & & & \\ & & & & \\ & & {} & & \\ & & & & \\ & & & & \\};
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

### `tabular` + a bit LaTeX3

The LaTeX3 isn't really necessary (`\int_mod:nn` is handy, though) – it's just integer arithmetics – and otherwise just uses a `tabular`.

The macros `\friendsofYes` and `\friendsofNo` specify how the individual cells should look like.

This doesn't use global counters or integer variables but instead does the math inline (which can get inefficient if your numbers are much bigger).

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\friendsof}{m m m}{{
  % #1 = columns (2), #2 = yes (2), #3 = nos (8)
  \setlength\tabcolsep{.4em}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{#1}{c|}}
    \hline
    \__friendsof_do:nnnn {#1}{#1}{#2}{#3}
    \int_compare:nNnT {\int_mod:nn{#2+#3}{#1}} > 0 { \\ \hline }
  \end{tabular}
}}
\cs_new:Nn \__friendsof_do:nnnn {
  \int_compare:nNnTF { #1 } = { 1 }
    { \__friendsof_do_:nnnnn { #2 }{ #2 }{ #3 }{ #4 }{ \\ \hline } }
    { \__friendsof_do_:nnnnn {#1-1}{ #2 }{ #3 }{ #4 }{ &         } } }
\cs_new:Nn \__friendsof_do_:nnnnn {
  \int_compare:nNnTF { #3 } > { 0 }
    { \friendsofYes #5  \__friendsof_do:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3-1}{#4} }
    { \int_compare:nNnT { #4 } > { 0 }
      { \friendsofNo #5 \__friendsof_do:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4-1} } } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand*\friendsofYes{{\color{blue!50}$\bullet$}\llap{$\circ$}}
\newcommand*\friendsofNo{$\circ$}
\begin{document}
Friends of $10 = \mathcolor{blue!50}{ 2} +  8$: \friendsof{2}{2}{8}\par
Friends of $ 9 = \mathcolor{blue!50}{ 4} +  5$: \friendsof{3}{4}{5}\par
Friends of $16 = \mathcolor{blue!50}{ 7} +  9$: \friendsof{4}{7}{9}\par
Friends of $24 = \mathcolor{blue!50}{12} + 12$: \friendsof{5}{12}{12}\par
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Oh!!! that's what the colours meant, I thought the two coloured ones denoted "2" and "8" and couldn't work out why they were both on top row:-) but it's simply partitioning the area.  I guess I'll have to+1 although it pains me to vote for a tikz answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, now you've also upvoted a `tabular`/`array` solution (with a small exercise in L3 even though it's barely using it in the end – I'm trying to get comfortable with it).