# Changing order of objects in a grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

The following code draws tens frames to show adding. The input is two numbers which present in different colours.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tensframeh}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%
        box/.style={rectangle,draw=black, minimum size=10mm},
    ]%


\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{ \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \ni using int(5*(\y-1)+\x)] in {1,2}{ \node[box] (\ni) at (\x,\y){};

            \ifnum\ni<\numexpr#1+1\relax
                     \filldraw[green] (\ni.center) circle (8pt);
            \else
                \ifnum\ni<\numexpr#1+#2+1\relax
                     \filldraw[blue] (\ni.center) circle (8pt);
                \fi
            \fi
            
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\tensframeh{1}{5}\ \tensframeh{3}{5}\ \tensframeh{2}{1}\ \tensframeh{6}{2}
\end{document}
```

The code is great, however, I just need to fill the frame from top to bottom, before going left to right. Does anyone know how this can be done?

---

Edit to clarify the question: The first argument of the command should represent the number of green circles, the second argument should represent the number of blue circles which should come after all green circles are positioned.

E.g.
`\tensframeh{3}{4}` would look like:
[image]

`\tensframeh{5}{0}` would look like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for neatening up the question.

Comment: Could you edit your question to make your code compilable? That makes it easier for people to help?

Comment: I don't understand this question even when I turn it into an MWE. What's the relationship between the code and the examples? Your examples concern single numbers, but you've posted code for a command which takes 2 with no indication of how you use it. Also, if you got the code from somewhere, you should attribute and link.

Comment: The question: 1) is totally unclear 2) absolutely not related to the examples provided 3) is not correctly redacted. Please edit it to make it a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and ask precisely what you're looking for. Your code is only filling two lines of 5 circles in green or black, depending on the input.

Comment: This reminds me of [Friends of 10](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/697253), just … differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably first draw a grid and then place the circles into it. You can use math functions such as `mod()` for the placement, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tensframeh}[2][green]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        box/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum size=10mm},
    ]

    \draw(0,0) grid (5,2);

    \foreach \x in {1,...,#2}{ 
        \filldraw[#1] ({ceil(\x/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];
    }
    
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\tensframeh{2}

\tensframeh{3}

\tensframeh[red]{7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want the cirlces in upper row to be green and the lower to be blue, you could change the above code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tensframeh}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        box/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum size=10mm},
    ]

    \draw(0,0) grid (5,2);

    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}{ 
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(mod(\x,2) == 1,"green","blue")}
        \filldraw[\pgfmathresult] ({ceil(\x/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\tensframeh{2}

\tensframeh{3}

\tensframeh{7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Now, if you want to define a command that takes two arguments, where the first arguments represents the number of green circles and the second the number of blue circles, you could change the above code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tensframeh}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        box/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum size=10mm},
    ]

    \draw(0,0) grid (5,2);

    \pgfmathparse{#1+#2}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\pgfmathresult}{ 
        \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\x <= #1,"green","blue")}
        \filldraw[\pgfmathresult] ({ceil(\x/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\tensframeh{3}{5}

\tensframeh{3}{6} 

\tensframeh{0}{6} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. The code with one colour works exactly as I'd hoped. 

With the two colour option, the idea was that the 2nd number specified the number of blue circles, and carried on from where the green left off. 

That is, 

\tensframeh{3}{5} would look like:

Top row(G G B B) Bottom row (G B B B) 

\tensframeh{3}{6} would look like:

Top row(G G B B B), Bottom row(G B B B )

and \tensframeh{0}{6} would look like:

top row(B B B) bottom row(B B B). Sorry hard to communicate in the comment!

Comment: @WendyTaylor I have to admit that, to me, this was really absolutely not clear from the original question! =) But thank you for your explanation. I added a variation of the code to the my original answer.

Comment: @WendyTaylor Maybe you can edit your question and add what you said in your comment above. This would really help understand what you were originally after and also make more clear why you used the approach you used. You can just use the Edit link below the question and add more information below a horizontal like (please do keep your original question for reference). You can then opt for re-opening of the question. I think, it would be a nice question then.

Comment: Thank you again for all your work on this, the code you have created is perfect. Thank you also for helping me see how I can improve the quality of my question too, hopefully the edits help other people find the question (and your fabulous answer!) useful.

Comment: @WendyTaylor I added one more paragraph to your edit to make it even more clear what you intend your command to do and also voted for reopening the question.